# which of these 2 classification models is best

Tags: self-study, classification

The difference between the two models is the label, which is slightly differently defined for the 2nd model. So for model 2 there are less data that fall in class 1.0 (87161 versus 155915).

Which of the two models would you prefer?
how should I evaluate a higher f1 score for the separate classes?

Model 1

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.69      0.90      0.78    299032

        1.0       0.56      0.23      0.32    155915

avg / total       0.65      0.67      0.63    454947
```

Model 2

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.87      0.93      0.90    367786

        1.0       0.58      0.40      0.47     87161

avg / total       0.81      0.83      0.82    454947
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that by moving from 1st model to the second, every individual metric is enhanced, so I would say the 2nd model is definitely better.